# Oxidation of toluene to benzoic acid

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds, stoichiometry

On [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potassium_permanganate) I found the reaction of the oxidation of toluene to benzoic acid:

$$\ce{5 C_6H_5CH_3 +6 KMnO_4 +9 H_2SO_4} \to \ce{5 C_6H_5COOH +14 H_2O +3 K_2SO_4 +6 MnSO_4}$$
which involves $35\, \ce{C},\, 58\, \ce{H}, \, 60\, \ce{O},\, 6\, \ce{K}, \, 6\, \ce{Mn}$.

But I managed to find a simpler version of the reaction:
$$\ce{C_6H_5CH_3 +6 KMnO_4 +5 H_2SO_4} \to \ce{C_6H_5COOH +6 H_2O +3 K_2SO_4 +6 MnSO_4}$$
which involves $7\, \ce{C},\, 18\, \ce{H}, \, 44\, \ce{O},\, 6\, \ce{K}, \, 6\, \ce{Mn}$.

Is one equation *more correct* than the other? Why/why not? Which reaction does actually occur when oxidizing toluene?

Comment: The second reaction isn't balanced. Count sulfur atoms. The first one from Wikipedia seems to be OK.

Comment: @andselisk Interestingly enough, OP counted all atoms of all elements *except* the number of sulfur atoms in either reaction;)

Comment: Alright, I absolutely forgot to count the sulfur atoms somehow...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Permanganate ion i acidic medium can have two reduction half reactions, $(1)$ and $(2)$:

$$\ce{MnO4- + 8H+ + 5e- -> Mn^2+ + 4H2O}\:\:\: E^\circ = \pu{1.50 V} \tag{1}$$
$$\ce{MnO4- + 4H+ + 3e- -> MnO2 + 2H2O}\:\:\: E^\circ = \pu{1.68 V} \tag{2}$$

Regardless of what oxidizing reagent has been used, the oxidation of toluene can be written as:

$$\ce{C6H5-CH3 + 2H2O -> C6H5-CO2H + 6H+ + 6e- } \:\:\: E^\circ = \pu{?? V} \tag{3}$$

I have no idea what would be the value of $E^\circ_\text{tol} $, but since the oxidation is not spontaneous, it should have been less than zero or close to zero (**Note:** More than a century years ago, Giacomo Ciamician, the pioneer of the modern day Green Chemistry, in collaboration with Paul Silber, has allowed toluene, *o*-xylene, *p*-xylene, and *m*-xylene to be influenced by oxygen and Sun light for about a year, and discovered the chemicals have been converted to the corresponding mono carboxylic acid as the main product; Ref.1 and 2). Yet toluene get oxidized by condition $(1)$, and hence, should get oxidized by condition $(2)$ as well, since $E^\circ_\text{(2)} \gt E^\circ_\text{(1)}$.

If you worked half-equations $(1)$ and $(3)$ you would get the redox reaction (disregarding $E^\circ$ values):

$$\ce{6MnO4- + 18H+ + 5C6H5-CH3 -> 5 C6H5-CO2H + 6Mn^2+ + 14H2O} \tag{4}$$

When you included counter ions $\ce{K+}$ and $\ce{SO4^2-}$, it gives your equation from Wikipedia:

$$\ce{6KMnO4 + 9H2SO4 + 5C6H5-CH3 -> 5 C6H5-CO2H + 6MnSO4 + 3 K2SO4 + 14H2O} \tag{5}$$

Thus, your first reaction is the correct one and, as everybody pointed out, the second reaction is incorrect solely because it is not correctly balanced.

Similarly, if you worked half-equations $(2)$ and $(3)$ you would get the redox reaction:

$$\ce{2MnO4- + 2H+ + C6H5-CH3 -> C6H5-CO2H + 2MnO2 + 2H2O} \tag{6}$$

But remember, under this conditions, $\ce{2MnO4- -> MnO2}$. Thus, it is not the same type. The major reason I gave this equation because you want to know what happens in this redox reaction. It is believe that "generally inorganic substance reduces acidic permanganate to $\ce{Mn^2+}$ state whereas organic substance
(containing oxidizable hydrogen) stop the reduction at the manganese dioxide $(\ce{MnO2})$ state (Ref.3).

**References:**

1. G. Ciamician, P. Silber, "Chemische Lichtwirkungen. XXII. Autooxydationen. I," *Ber. dtsch. Chem. Ges.* **1912**, *45(1)*, 38-43 (https://doi.org/10.1002/cber.19120450107).
2. For review on G. Ciamician's pioneering work: Angelo Albini, Maurizio Fagnoni, "Green chemistry and photochemistry were born at the same time," *Green Chem.* **2004**, *6(1)*, 1-6 (DOI: 10.1039/B309592D).
3. Mukul Chauhan, "Permanganate Oxidation mechanisms of Alkylarenes," *IOSR Journal of Applied Chemistry* **2014**, *7(6)*, 16-27 (DOI: 10.9790/5736-07611627).

Comment: The long article by Mahindaraine is very interesting, but it contains the same mistake repeated through all its lines. It produces a neutral substance C5H5-CO2 that does not exist. It should be either either benzoic acid C6H5COOH or the benzoate ion C6H5COO-. And the equation (3) is not balanced. There is 7 H at the left-hand-side and 6 H at th right hand side. The equation (4) is also wrong, with 33 H at left-hand side and 28 at right.

Comment: Can't a person make a mistake? (_e.g._, you have a mistake in your comment as well) Should have corrected rather than complaining.

Comment: To the down voter, give me a good reason why you have down voted my answer. Is there anything wrong about this answer?

Comment: @MathewMahindaratne We can't control what people like right? That's up to their own discretion, maybe it was before your edit. But don't worry I upvoted your answer, it was really an informative one, but I feel the question as it's stated is not that intriguing.